# How to mock Dependent Modules in Jasmine for Large Number of dependencies in Angular 9?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, dependency-injection, jasmine, karma-runner

I want to write a Unit test for One of the Components in the Angular Project. 
 The Main Component class has 5-6 dependencies and it extends another Class which has around 7 more dependencies. 
What will be the best way to configure the TestBed for this Component? Do I need to mock all the 12-13 classes to Run the Tests

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare all functions you need in the component you want to test. You can import or mock them. Mocking is much faster.

You can ignore other components in your test with schema in TestBed Module (this ignores all other child components).

```
schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
```

You can mock services like this

```
providers: [{provide: MyService: useClass: {}]
```

Comment: In the Last line use class: {}. Can we do this for all Services, Directive and pipes that are not required for Unit Testing?